# Экранировать символы

Tags: modx, xss, formit, input, htmlspecialchars

Здравствуйте!

На сайте под управлением MODX Revolution 2.2.8-pl (traditional) есть форма, собранна на FormIt. Мне нужно экранировать спец. символы для защиты от XSS атак.

В пример могу привести одно из полей этой формы:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Имя" id="name2" name="name2:required:stripTags" required value="[[+fi.name2]]">
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вадим, используй [фильтры ввода/вывода](http://community.modx-cms.ru/blog/documentation/36.html)

В данном конкретном случае должно быть так:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Имя" id="name2" name="name2:required:stripTags" required value="[[+fi.name2:esc]]">
```